# Populate ComboBox from Database query

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I see many of the answers to similar question where people are saying that in order to get the value of the item loaded in combobox you need to use

```
  combobox1.displayMamer =""
  combobox1.valuemember=""
  combobox1.datasource=""
```

But this stuff does not work.....

here is what I have....

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Using con As New SqlConnection(sConnection)
        con.Open()
        Using com As New SqlCommand("Select Code1, Code2 from  tblTable6 where fldname ='Things'", con)
            Using rdr = com.ExecuteReader
                If rdr.HasRows Then
                    Do While rdr.Read = True
                        ComboBox1.Items.Add(rdr.GetString(0))
                        ''''missing something here
                    Loop
                    con.Close()
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I'm selecting Code1 and Code2 from Table, i want to be able to display code1 and when selected, I want to be able to have the value of Code2, but with displayMember, and ValueMember, I'm not seeing any result.

EDIT: Here's all my code:

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Using con As New SqlConnection(sConnection)

        Using com As New SqlCommand("Select Label, Code from Table.....", con)
            con.Open()
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            Dim rows = dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)
            ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Code"
            ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Label"
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Dim rows = dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader) --- this line gets underlined

ERROR says: Expression does not produce value

EDIT2:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Using con As New SqlConnection(sConnection)
        con.Open()
        Using com As New SqlCommand("Select Label, Code from  tblData where fldname ='M'", con)

            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Code"
            ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Label"
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Now I get another error saying that: Cannot bind to the new value member.
This happens on combobox1.valuemember="Label"

Comment: You don't need that HasRows check.  `Do While rdr.Read` will just skip the loop if there aren't any rows.

Comment: change it to use your actual SQL - column, table names WHERE clause etc.  I changed it to present a more general solution since I have no idea about the data

Comment: @plutonix - i did change the SQL statement, I deleted it right before I pasted it in here

Comment: Get rid of the rows thing - I got it confused with a different way to fill a Datatable.  if you need the number of rows, use `dt.Rows.Count`.  sorry

Comment: @plutonix please see edit2. No worries thank you for your help!

Comment: Is there really a column named "Label" in your db?  What data type is it?

Comment: Yes - i flipped the code and changed it to "code" it still fails on the valuemember line

Comment: @plutonix varchar(20)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than populating the items collection, you can bind a `DataTable` to the control to be used as the `Datasource`.  Then, you can tell it which element to display and which value to submit to you when there is a selection:

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(sConnection)
    Using com As New SqlCommand("Select Id, Name FROM ....", con)
        con.Open()

        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)
        cbox1.Datasource = dt
        cbox.DisplayMember = "Name"
        cbox.ValueMember = "Id"
    End Using
End Using
```

"Name" and "Id" would be column names from the database table.  The event you probably want to work with in this case would be the `SelectedValueChanged` and `SelectedValue` would hold the ID related to the item selected.  This will be returned as `Object` so you may need to cast it back to whatever it is.

You can also bind to `List(Of T)` collections in the same way.  In that case, the `SelectedItem` could be the entire object.  For instance, using a `List(of Employee)`, `SelectedItem` would be the object for the Employee the user selected.

Comment: am i not supposed to check if there is any data? or loop through?

Comment: No need to unless the app needs to do something when there is no related data.  If rows is 0 from the `dt.Load` then there were no matching rows - no loop needed for populating though.