# Visual Studio - Outlook addin - Fill Combobox from SQL database and why does string value return like this?

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, ribbon

I'm creating an outlook addin with MS Visual Studio. From the ribbon, the user clicks a button which opens a winform (called NewEntry) with some comboboxes which I would like to populate with data from an SQL database.

For populating a single combobox (named Companies) my code is:

```
    public NewEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM PrivateContractors", cnn);
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        cmd.Dispose();
        cnn.Close();
        Companies.DataSource = dt;
        try
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Companies.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(dr["name"])); //this is line 67
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(e));
        }
    }
```

This is the exception message:

[image]

When the form then opens, my ComboBox is populated with the expected amount of fields but they're all named System.Data.DataRowView

When I remove the foreach statement, I get no exceptions but the combobox values are all still System.Data.DataRowView

Anyone know where I'm going wrong and what I can do to rectify this error?

Comment: You are invoking `Show` for each row / value individually. You need to populate the associated `Items` collection e.g. via `Add` or `AddRange`.

Comment: As I say, I've already tried converting the string into objects one-by-one and it doesn't work. Also, AddRange doesn't seem to be a valid line either. Can you show me what your approach would be?

Comment: Did you try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40139886/populate-combobox-from-database-query or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900062/c-sharp-fill-combo-box-from-sql-datatable?

Comment: Thanks for sending me these, the second one I hadn't tried quite like that before! I've updated my original post with the progress, including the exception I'm getting etc.. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Now you have the same issue as in the second question mentioned. Use the solution / top-rated Answer as your model.

Comment: Spot-on, will post the solution here. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution here:

```
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM PrivateContractors", cnn);
        SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            Companies.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(dataReader["Name"]));
        }
        dataReader.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        cnn.Close();
    }
```